# Lack of space? It still has 2gb more

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I have 8gb disk space total, and still has more than 2gb:

```
root@ip-172-31-19-35:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  180M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.0G  2.5G  68% /
```

But when I run the server or try something make, it always fails with:

> bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Or fails with somekind of "Unix.ENOSPC" error happens and program crashes.

Does anyone know why this happens? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a inode issue. `df -i` will give a percent inode used.

If inode's are your problem finding an lot of small files and archiving and deleting or just deleting them will free inode's. `du ~/ | sort -n | head -n 10` will list the 10 smallest files in the current users home dir.